# Why Atomic size decreases left to right in a period in MPT?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In modern periodic table,  atomic size decreases as we move from left to right in a period. As no. of electron increase left  to right but why atomic size decreases?

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.‎

Comment: Though more electrons are being added, the electrons add to the same orbit. So, as we know nuclear charge is distant dependent, i.e., inversely proportional to atomic radius. And as the no of electrons increases the nuclear charge also increases. With increase in nuclear charge, the atomic size eventually decrease.

Answer (score 1):

The Modern Periodic table is made according to increasing number of their atomic numbers . So if we move from left to right in a period the no of electrons as well as the no of protons goes on increasing . The electrons are added to the same orbit or energylevel but the nuclear charge increases by one in each step due to increase in the number of proton by one in each step. So the inward pull increases and the outer orbital shrinks. As a result the atomic size decreases moving towards right in the modern periodic table.